# I'm trying to add ".0" onto any single digit numbers in my vector

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

Can someone please explain why this code isn't working? I want the `nums` character vector to output "4.4" "" "5.0" but I'm getting an error message. Something about a `do.call()`.

In addition to knowing why it's doing this can someone provide an easier way of turning the "5" into "5.0" but leaving the other numbers as they are. Please keep in mind I actually have many numbers so something like `nums[3] <- "5.0"` wouldn't be useful.

```
y <- 0
nums <- c("4.4", "", "5")

for(x in nums){

  y <- 0 + 1

  if(nchar(x) == 1){
    nums[y] <- paste(x, ".0", sep = "")
  }else{}
}
```

Running the code above I get this error message:

> Error in do.call(base::call, c(name = "{", else_lines), quote = TRUE) : 
>     second argument must be a list

Comment: A few comments not directly related to your error: (1) `y <- 0 + 1` is a pointless line, it's equivalent to `y <- 1`, which doesn't need to be updated every time through the loop. Maybe you meant `y <- y + 1`? But you'd be better off just looping over a sequence, e.g. `for (i in seq_along(nums))` instead of `for(x in nums)` -- then you don't have to keep track of the iteration number separately.

Comment: (2) `else{}` does nothing if those brackets are empty. Just omit it.

Comment: I created some code like this with much more stuff in it and usually just copy and paste it when i need it. I must have typed this code out instead as it's smaller and accidentally put 0 instead of y and yes i think you may be right with the seq_along() being better. I got the idea of using the y + 1 from somewhere early on when learning R and had just stuck with it. I was running this code at work when i got the error message but i've just tried it at home and it now works fine with no error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by `format()`:

```
x <- format(as.numeric(nums), nsmall = 1, trim = T)
x[x == "NA"] <- ""
x
# [1] "4.4" ""    "5.0"
```

The argument `nsmall` controls the minimum number of digits to the right of the decimal point in formatting real/complex numbers in non-scientific formats. For example:

```
format(12.3, nsmall = 3)
# [1] "12.300"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sub`:

```
nums1 <- c("4.4", "", "5")
sub('^(\\d)$', '\\1.0', nums1)
# [1] "4.4" ""    "5.0"
```

or we can add a `+` to generalize it to any number of digits without a decimal place:

```
nums2 <- c("4.4", "", "5", "15.5", "20")
sub('^(\\d+)$', '\\1.0', nums2)
# [1] "4.4"  ""     "5.0"  "15.5" "20.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Darren's solution

```
x <- sprintf("%.1f", as.numeric(c("4.4", "", "5")))
replace(x, is.na(x), "")
[1] "4.4" ""    "5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for dots and add .0 if needed :

```
nums <- c("4.4", "", "5")
points <- grepl("\\.", nums)
nums[!points & nchar(nums) > 0] <- paste0(nums[!points & nchar(nums) > 0], ".0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```
gsub("(?<!\\.)(\\d)$", "\\1\\.0", nums, perl = T)
```

Enlarged example:

```
nums <- c("4.4", "", "5", "34.5", "555", "-4", "-4.4", "-34.4")
```

Output:

```
[1] "4.4"   ""      "5.0"   "34.5"  "555.0" "-4.0"  "-4.4"  "-34.4"
```

This basically looks for any number (`(\\d)`) that is present at the end of the string (`$`) and doesn't have a `.` before it (`(?<!\\.)`).

The idea behind this negative lookbehind is that it could also function in cases of negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Using your logic with a vectorized `ifelse()` instead of a `for` loop:

```
nums <- c("4.4", "", "5")
ifelse(nchar(nums) == 1, paste0(nums, ".0"), nums)
# [1] "4.4" ""    "5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gsub("^([0-9]$)()","\\1.0\\2",nums,perl=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
[1] "4.4" ""    "5.0"
```